# Selecting column names that have specified value

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are receiving rather large files, of which we have no control over the format of, that are being bulk-loaded into a SQL Server table via SSIS to be later imported into our internal structure. These files can contain over 800 columns, and often the column names are not immediately recognizable.

As a result, we have a large table that represents the contents of the file with over 800 `Varchar` columns.

The problem is: I know what specific values I'm looking for in this data, but I do not know what column contains it.  And eyeballing the data to find said column is neither efficient nor ideal.

My question is: is it at all possible to search a table by some value `N` and return the column names that have that value? I'd post some code that I've tried, but I really don't  know where to start on this one... or if it's even possible.

For example:

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   ...
------------------------------------------------------------
'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'c' ...
```

If I were to search this table for the value 'b', I would want to get back the following results:

```
Columns
---------
F
J
K
```

Is something like this possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script will search all tables and all string columns for a specific string.  You might be able to adapt this for your needs:

```
DECLARE @tableName sysname
DECLARE @columnName sysname
DECLARE @value varchar(100)
DECLARE @sql varchar(2000)
DECLARE @sqlPreamble varchar(100)

SET @value = 'EDUQ4' -- *** Set this to the value you're searching for *** --

SET @sqlPreamble = 'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM '

DECLARE theTableCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' 
       AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%temp%' AND TABLE_NAME != 'dtproperties' AND TABLE_NAME != 'sysdiagrams'
     ORDER BY TABLE_NAME

OPEN theTableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM theTableCursor INTO @tableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 -- spin through Table entries
BEGIN
    DECLARE theColumnCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
         WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tableName AND (DATA_TYPE = 'nvarchar' OR DATA_TYPE = 'varchar')
         ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

    OPEN theColumnCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM theColumnCursor INTO @columnName

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 -- spin through Column entries
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @tableName + ' WHERE ' + @columnName + ' LIKE ''' + @value + 
                   ''') PRINT ''Value found in Table: ' + @tableName + ', Column: ' +  @columnName + ''''
        EXEC (@sqlPreamble + @sql)
        FETCH NEXT FROM theColumnCursor INTO @columnName
    END
    CLOSE theColumnCursor
    DEALLOCATE theColumnCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM theTableCursor INTO @tableName
END
CLOSE theTableCursor
DEALLOCATE theTableCursor
```

Comment: Oh wow, this worked perfectly!  I never even thought of doing something like this.

Answer (score 1):

One option you have is to be a little creative using XML in SQL Server.

Turn a row at a time into XML using cross apply and query for the nodes that has a certain value in a second cross apply.

Finally you output the distinct list of node names.

```
declare @Value nvarchar(max)

set @Value= 'b'

select distinct T3.X.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)') as ColName
from YourTable as T1
  cross apply (select T1.* for xml path(''), type) as T2(X)
  cross apply T2.X.nodes('*[text() = sql:variable("@Value")]') as T3(X)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fea0/1)

Comment: I really wish I could accept more than one answer.  This works really well, but it's a bit slower and more taxing on the CPU than @pmbAustin's method.  But I love the compactness of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the files are RegEx will be must faster than performing a generic search in SQL.

If you are forced to use SQL @pmbAustin's answer is the way to go.  Be warned, it won't run quickly.