# searching a string in sql from any column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote this for searching a string in sql from any column in a table but in some cases it is responding abnormally. The example is given here.

```
declare @tablepay table
(
    payno varchar(500),
    lastmodified nvarchar(500)
)

declare @columnname table
(
    [rownumber] INT IDENTITY,
    colname varchar(500)
)

insert into @tablepay (payno, lastmodified)
   select 'PAY/2014','abcd'

insert into @columnname(colname)
  select TN.N.value('local-name(.)', 'sysname') as ColumnName
  from 
      (select TV.* 
       from (select 1) as D(N)
       outer apply (select top(0) * from @tablepay) as TV for xml path(''), elements xsinil, type) as TX(X)
       cross apply TX.X.nodes('*') as TN(N)

DECLARE @count INT
DECLARE @begincount INT
DECLARE @clname as VARCHAR(50)='';

SET @begincount = 1

select @count = count(*) from @columnname

declare @tlname varchar(50)
set @tlname = '@tablepay'

WHILE @begincount <= @count
BEGIN
    set @clname = (select colname from @columnname where rownumber = @begincount)

    declare @text as varchar(100)

    select * from @tablepay where @clname like '%f%'

    SET @begincount = @begincount + 1
END
```

Comment: Please expand on 'responding abnormally' and please add the appropriate RDBMS tag - is it SQL Server?

Comment: Yes this is SQL Server, here when I give like '%f%' it returns a row. But in that row there is no 'f'

Comment: The code you have posted makes no sense. You insert a single row into `@tablepay`, then you select from it _using a where clause which bears no relation to the records in the table_. In short your code makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1):

You said `when I give like '%f%' it returns a row. But in that row there is no 'f'`

That should be correct. In your below query `@clname` is not part of table variable `@tablepay`. so it just check whether the `@clname` parameter value contains `f` character in it and if `true` return row from table `@tablepay` but that doesn't guarantee at all that table `@tablepay` has to have a row which contains `f` character in on of his column.

```
select * from @tablepay where @clname like '%f%'
```

Per Structure of you table `@tablepay` as below

```
declare @tablepay table
(
    payno varchar(500),
    lastmodified nvarchar(500)
)
```

If you want to search for character `f` in columns of that table then search table columns directly like

```
select * from @tablepay where payno like '%f%' OR lastmodified like '%f%'
```

Comment: Can you suggest a way for searching a similar string in particular table in all columns

Comment: here in this case how can I pass column name dynamically?

Comment: Not sure I understood. Which column you want to pass dynamically?

Comment: Need to pass the column name where we have to search the string.

Comment: You need to use a dynamic query for that. BTW, that's altogether a separate question and as such should be posted separately with all relevant information.

Comment: Can you please suggest a way to search a string from a table by passing the column name dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this existing answer for an example of what I *THINK* you're asking for:

[Selecting column names that have specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481973/selecting-column-names-that-have-specified-value/23482530#23482530)

This particular answer searches all string columns in all tables in the database.  You can easily modify it to search for all string columns in just one particular table.  It should give you the framework you need to tweak to get what you want.