# List of table names and column names with specific column value

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

How can I get a List of table names and column names in a database where a column value like '%something%'
For an example, I have a Movie database, I need a List of table names and column names where the column value = 'tom cruise'

I am using MS SQL and MySQL database
Thanks

Comment: This is an odd thing to try and implement.  If you don't know *where* in your database your data is held, then you've probably designed your database badly.  You might consider moving to an [entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model), using [fulltext search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/fulltext-search.html) (over multiple columns), or even deploying a search engine like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) or [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/).

Comment: You're using *both* MS SQL *and* MySQL?  Could you elaborate on your configuration a little further?  They are two unrelated, competing RDBMS products—whilst it is possible to connect them together, it's not very common.  I suspect you're only using one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this previous question and answer... the answer contains a script that scans a database and lists out all the tables/columns with a matching value:

[Selecting column names that have specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481973/selecting-column-names-that-have-specified-value/23482530#23482530)

Answer (score 0):

You can get tables names and columns names using `information_schema`.

And `Information_schema` contains following column names using which you can filter your results:

[image]