# SQL Server Cursor Error

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I want find the records which have `~` in the table.

I am using cursor to, but I am getting unexpected error.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
DECLARE @test    VARCHAR(5000)
DECLARE @column_name     VARCHAR(2000)
Declare @TABLE_NAME_MAIN VARCHAR(200)

SET @TABLE_NAME_MAIN = 'Ar_Receipt_Item_OHM'

DECLARE cur_name 
CURSOR FOR
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TABLE_NAME_MAIN

OPEN cur_name
FETCH NEXT FROM cur_name INTO @column_name

WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0
BEGIN

SET @test = N'SELECT top 2 * FROM OHMPreStage.dbo.'+@TABLE_NAME_MAIN+' WHERE '+@column_name+' LIKE ''%~%'''

exec @test      

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_name INTO @column_name
END
CLOSE cur_name
DEALLOCATE cur_name
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Error:

> Msg 911, Level 16, State 4, Line 24
>   Database 'SELECT top 2 * FROM OHMPreStage' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change:

```
exec @test
```

To

```
exec (@test)
```

`EXEC` is for executing stored procedures, `EXEC()` the function puts together a dynamic string and executes it.

Comment: Thank You
That Worked...I was breaking my head since from 1 hr

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to have issues searching columns with "LIKE" That aren't string columns.

You should check out the answer to this question here, which gives you a script that scans all tables in a database for specific string content:

[Selecting column names that have specified value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481973/selecting-column-names-that-have-specified-value/23482530#23482530)

Just substitute your search string '%~%', and if you need to, limit the tables searched to just the one (or set of) tables you need.