# shortest way to find a data within many tables and databases

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a project with 20+ databases and thousands of table. I am able to check if the column name or table name exists using sys.objetcs and sys.columns and with little guessing and inner join I could find the columns and tables. Is there a way to find the data in specific by iterating through the databases or any other means. I am trying to find the data that is displayed in the output but I don't know which table it comes from.

Comment: Possible relevance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481973/selecting-column-names-that-have-specified-value

Comment: that's the script I am looking for. many thanks.