# Finding a special character in one of the columns of many tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

The import is causing a crash because of invalid character for XML that is coming from client's `SQL Server` data.
From the log file looks like it is a right arrow **"->"** .

All I know is it is coming from a column - I don't know which column - in one of my tables - about 20 tables -

How can I give them a query to run on their database to find out where is this bad data located ?

Comment: You might want to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481973/selecting-column-names-that-have-specified-value/23482530#23482530

Comment: Get a listing of the columns using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` to build a dynamic SQL query that performs a `LIKE` check on all of the columns.

Comment: I've had a similar problem. I would create dynamic SQL based on the comments above. If I remember correctly, I believe that character was a `CHAR(24)`.

Comment: thanks, @bjones , mine I think is a CHAR(26) , the error log they send me says HEX of "1A"

Comment: Ah, yes. You're right. It was `CHAR(26)`. I simply used a `REPLACE()` function when I found out which column it was.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem. I found the characters by using Notepad++. There is a menu for encoding. Changing this causes some hidden characters to appear. I changed it to ANSI. Also, I have found hidden characters in Microsoft Word using the "Show or hide formatting marks" button.(It looks like a backwards P).